# Wildcard string * and ? comparison in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm working on evaluating string wildcard combinations that include wildcards in a string. Specifically, I need to handle both the "*" and "?" wildcards in my regular expressions.

for example : if I had a string PHO12RO I  like to uses wildcard within the string like PH?12RO OR maybe PH?12* for example so the string PHO12RO  would evaluate to true however string PHO13RO would evaluate to false if I used this pattern PH?12*

I've managed to handle the "*" wildcard with in the string ex(PHO12*) using regular expressions, but I'm struggling to match the ?" wildcard in my string ex(PH?12RO).

Below is a snippet of my code where I've used the "*" wildcard successfully:

Could someone guide me on how to modify my regular expression to also handle the the string scenario PH?12* or PH?12RO.

```
async function WildCardEvaluator(field:string, rule:string) : Promise<Boolean> {
      // for this solution to work on any string, no matter what characters it has
  var escapeRegex = (field:string) => field.replace(/([.*+?^=!:${}()|\[\]\/\\])/g, "\\$1");

  // "."  => Find a single character, except newline or line terminator
  // ".*" => Matches any string that contains zero or more characters
  rule = rule.split("*").map(escapeRegex).join(".*");

  // "^"  => Matches any string with the following at the beginning of it
  // "$"  => Matches any string with that in front at the end of it
  rule = "^" + rule + "$"

  //Create a regular expression object for matching string
  var regex = new RegExp(rule);

  //Returns true if it finds a match, otherwise it returns false
  return regex.test(field);
  }
```

Comment: What does your `?` mean? Because it looks like you're not asking about `*` and `?` _in_ regex, but how to rewrite a custom string with `*` and `?` characters _to_ regex

Comment: ?? The shell wildcard `?` means pretty much the same thing as regex `.`.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans 
for example : if I had a string PHO12RO I  like to uses wildcard within the string like PH?12RO OR maybe PH?12* the string PHO12RO  would evaluate to true however string PHO13RO would evaluate to false if I used this pattern PH?12*

Comment: @Pointy I didn't see the post talk about shell wildcards. Depending on context `?` can also be a token (e.g. "a digit cluster, which can only exist in this position" rather than "any single letter"), so I just wanted to make sure it's unambiguous what `?` has to map to.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans yea what the term "wildcard" means here is not clear, but the way "*" and "?" are described, that's all I could conclude.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function wildcardToRegex(wildcard: string): RegExp {
  return new RegExp(
    '^' +
    wildcard.replaceAll(
      /[.*+?^=!:${}()|\[\]\/\\]/g,
      (s) => 
        s === '?' ? '.'    // map ? to .
        : s === '*' ? '.*' // map * to .*
        : '\\' + s,        // escape other
    )
    + '$'
  )
}
```

Comment: And, of course, be careful with `*********` which will hang up if you won't

Comment: this is perfect and I learn a lot from your code! thank you!